# Segmentation Fault error while running C program

Tags: c, memory

I'm new using Valgrind for the first time to check memory errrors. I'm running C program and seeing the errors that are not related to the C program but all the errors are from memory (open64.c:48, _IO_file_open (fileops.c:189), .....). I don't know where these files are located. Could you please help me how to resolve this?

```
==40910== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==40910== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==40910== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==40910== Command: ./dd
==40910== 
==40910== Syscall param openat(filename) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==40910==    at 0x4ABCEAB: open (open64.c:48)
==40910==    by 0x4A3F195: _IO_file_open (fileops.c:189)
==40910==    by 0x4A3F459: _IO_file_fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:281)
==40910==    by 0x4A31B0D: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:75)
==40910==    by 0x4A31B0D: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:86)
==40910==    by 0x109336: main (in /home/Desktop/dd)
==40910==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==40910== 
==40910== Invalid read of size 4
==40910==    at 0x4A317D7: fgets (iofgets.c:47)
==40910==    by 0x109427: main (in /home/Desktop/dd)
==40910==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==40910== 
==40910== 
==40910== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==40910==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==40910==    at 0x4A317D7: fgets (iofgets.c:47)
==40910==    by 0x109427: main (in /home/Desktop/dd)

==40910==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==40910==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==40910==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==40910==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==40910==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 16777216.
==40910== 
==40910== HEAP SUMMARY:
==40910==     in use at exit: 984 bytes in 3 blocks
==40910==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 1 frees, 1,456 bytes allocated
==40910== 
==40910== LEAK SUMMARY:
==40910==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==40910==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==40910==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==40910==    still reachable: 984 bytes in 3 blocks
==40910==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==40910== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==40910== 
==40910== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==40910== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: If it's C, don't tag it with C++.

Comment: Did you compile with `-g` option?

Comment: "seeing the errors that are not related to the C program": /home/Desktop/dd is _your_ program. Start to search for errors there, not in the library files.

Comment: Yes, I did tried with -g as well. It is also giving me same result

Comment: No, it is not _giving me same result_; it shows the line numbers in `main` where your errors manifest themselves.

Comment: The functions are related to `stdio.h`. You probably did an (e.g.): `FILE *fp = fopen(...);` but didn't do `fclose(fp);` before exiting the program.

Comment: @CraigEstey My crystal ball is telling me that OP is doing fopen(argv[1]) without checking first that argc > 1

Answer (score 3):

**Without the code this is certainly the easiest question to answer!**

"**unaddressable**" = point to byte that do not belong to you.
valgrind warns you because probably the memory that you freed in memory is not yours (or, at least, it is no longer reserved for the use you had asked for), and then you could be using it for another thing and interpret a value that is not.
Why doesn't it break when you run without valgrind? Good, for starters - that's what you say. For onething your code is not doing appropriate error checking. So it may be breaking inside, so you wont notice it. All I could say is bad coding style may compile and runs without showing you any errors but in the background it maybe suffocating itself or the thing which it is running on.

**Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd`**
tells you you're dereferencing a NULL pointer (Address 0x0 ...) meaning fopen failed and returned 0/NULL.

Try fixing it? like..

-Check if returned fopen() valid FILE* to avoid undefined behavior when trying to read from input_file.
-Make sure that if fgets() succeeds (does not return NULL) to avoid undefined behavior.

**PS: Read "The 8 Commandments for C Programmers**"

**2.** Thou shalt not follow the NULL pointer, for chaos and madness await thee at its end.

**6.** If a function be advertised to return an error code in the event of difficulties, thou shalt check for that code, yea, even though the checks triple the size of thy code and produce aches in thy typing fingers, for if thou thinkest “it cannot happen to me”, the gods shall surely punish thee for thy arrogance.

Comment: Are you referring to [The 10 Commandments for C Programmers](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ten-commandments.html) — which can be found at many places including the one linked? Feel free to update your answer with a link and corrected title — you can flag this comment 'no longer needed' once you've done so.

Comment: I'll also observe that the 10 Commandments are a bit ossified — some of its guidance is not as relevant in the 21st century as it was before there was a C standard. (It was written before 1994.) I've not run `lint` in years, and the modern heresy is "All the world uses an Intel/AMD x86/64 chip".

Comment: wow! so this is me humor aside. The original post "10 commandments for C programmers" I know its out-dated and we all know it. But some are not obsolete, which is why I mentioned it as the "8 commandments" which is or at least I think is still valid from the original list. You can find a bunch of them on the wild weird web.

Comment: I guessed his/her real problem was with the code. At the time of writing that comment I believed he/she must know the ways to circumvent when such and such errors showup. Maybe the only problem was because of a bad "style"? that it is hard to even call C? There will always be few people in this world which has no meaning to a "unreadable mess" anything we throw to them can be readable but for newbies its NOT. I do not know which/what his/her problem lies but I answered the question in a manner where anyone can read and understand whats going on.

Comment: I do not wish to insult nor offend anyone, but sometimes I do without even knowing. Nonetheless I just wanted the person who asked the question to understand what he/she is doing, like maybe learning C or C++ from scratch using a decent book would help. When you have a problem, you can ask for help and then find and fix it. and then there is the other way where you know why there even have to be a problem? so there will be less or no error or even if it did its easier finding and fixing it your ownself. It makes all sense in my head but if this is all non-sense to you, then please ignore it!

Answer (score 1):

Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

That means you are using a NULL pointer ( NULL = (void*)0 AND 0 = 0x0 in hexadecimal). Try check if a pointer is NULL before using it.

Edit: if you are using "fopen", this function returns NULL if it cannot open the file.